# ValueError: Tensor must be from the same graph as Tensor with Bidirectinal RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

I'm doing text tagger using Bidirectional dynamic RNN in tensorflow.
After maching input's dimension, I tried to run a Session. 
this is blstm setting parts:

```
fw_lstm_cell = BasicLSTMCell(LSTM_DIMS)
bw_lstm_cell = BasicLSTMCell(LSTM_DIMS)

(fw_outputs, bw_outputs), _ = bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(fw_lstm_cell,
                                                        bw_lstm_cell,
                                                        x_place,
                                                        sequence_length=SEQLEN,
                                                        dtype='float32')
```

and this is runing part:

```
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Placehoder Settings
    x_place, y_place = set_placeholder(BATCH_SIZE, EM_DIMS, MAXLEN)

    # BLSTM Model Building
    hlogits = tf_kcpt.build_blstm(x_place)

    # Compute loss
    loss = tf_kcpt.get_loss(log_likelihood)

    # Training
    train_op = tf_kcpt.training(loss)

    # load Eval method
    eval_correct = tf_kcpt.evaluation(logits, y_place)

    # Session Setting & Init
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    # tensor summary setting
    summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR, sess.graph)

    # Save
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # Run epoch
    for step in range(EPOCH):
        start_time = time.time()

        feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(KCPT_SET['train'], x_place, y_place)
        _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

But, it give me the error:

> ValueError: Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/stack_2:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32).

Help me, please

Comment: Could you please provide the full code??

Answer (score 46, accepted):

TensorFlow stores all operations on an operational graph. This graph defines what functions output to where, and it links it all together so that it can follow the steps you have set up in the graph to produce your final output. If you try to input a Tensor or operation on one graph into a Tensor or operation on another graph it will fail. Everything must be on the same execution graph.

Try removing `with tf.Graph().as_default():`

TensorFlow provides you a default graph which is referred to if you do not specify a graph. You are probably using the default graph in one spot and a different graph in your training block.

There does not seem to be a reason you are specifying a graph as default here and most likely you are using separate graphs on accident. If you really want to specify a graph then you probably want to pass it as a variable, not set it like this.

Comment: You can alternatively reset the graph by `tf.reset_default_graph()` and then execute all code blocks again. this often removes the problem

Comment: Why `with tf.Graph().as_default():` don't reuse already created graph?

Comment: I assigned to variable and reused it later, but still didnt work. ValueError: Tensor("optimizations:0", shape=(3,), dtype=string) must be from the same graph as Tensor("PaddedBatchDatasetV2:0", shape=(), dtype=variant).

Comment: @mrgloom `tf.Graph()` creates a new graph

Answer (score 6):

If you are using tf 2.x with Keras - then maybe disable-ling eager execution before building the model graph could help. So to disable eager execution - adding the following line before defining the model.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score -5):

Or you may go to 'Kernel' and select ' Restart and clear output'. :D