# What does worker mean in fit_generator in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, pipeline

I have a large dataset stored in `tfrecord` file  like 333 for training so I shrard the data into multiple files like 1024 tfrecords file instead of one. And I used the input pipeline in tf.Dataset Api. like:

```
ds= ds.TFRecordsDataset(files).shuffle().repeat().shuffle().repeat()
ds = ds.prefetch(1)
```

And I have my own generator that yields `batch_x, batch_y`.

My problem is the code is working only when I set the `workers=0` in `fit_generator()`.

Whenever I set it to more than 0 , it will give the following error

> ValueError: Tensor("PrefetchDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Iterator:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).

And the documentation about what it means if `workers =` 0 is not enough, they said

> If 0, will execute the generator on the main thread.

I found similar problem in github [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10110), but with no solution yet.

There is another kind of similar problem one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616625/valueerror-tensor-must-be-from-the-same-graph-as-tensor-with-bidirectinal-rnn-i), but I am different because I used Keras not tensor flow and I didn't use with `tf.Graph().as_default()`. The suggested that there is two graph instead of one, so the solution was by removing `tf.Graph().as_default()`. When I checked the graph, I noticed that the all map function related to my input pipeline is in different graph( subgraph) and it can not attached to the main graph. like below:

[image]

And I should mention that this is a two stage training. First I build one network taking image_based dataset and the network ispre trained on `imagene`t and I just trained my classifier. The dataset was in `hdf5` file and it can be fit in memory. While in second stage I am using the trained network in first stage and attached some block to it and my dataset here is `tfrecod` file thats why I used a `tf.Dataset API` for my input pipeline. So this new input pipeline is not exsit in the first graph for the first stage. But it should not matter, I just used the pretreated network as a base mode then I add to it different block . So it is totally new model.

And the main reason I want to change the worker, because my GPU utils always zero,thats mean the CPU is bottleneck, meaning that the Cpu take a lot of time to extract the data. And my GPU always waiting. Thats why the training take along time, like one epoch 9 hours.

Can any one explain what the error means?

Comment: Which Keras version are you using?

Comment: @user3483203, I used the version '2.1.5' .  I added more details about the problem in the post.